# How to get web.config appSettings as ConfigurationSection not NameValueCollection

Tags: asp.net, .net

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings Property
Returns a NameValueCollection object that contains the contents of the AppSettingsSection object for the current application's default configuration.

but I need AppSettingsSection object because I need to change it configSource property in runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var appSettingsSection = (AppSettingsSection)configuration.GetSection("appSettings");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the `AppSettingsSection` with the [Configuration.GetSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.getsection.aspx) method or with the [Configuration.AppSetting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.appsettings.aspx) property.

To get an `Configuration` object you need to use the `ConfigurationManager.Open...` or the `WebConfigurationManager.Open...` methods:

```
string sectionName = "appSettings";
var config = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
AppSettingsSection appSettingSection =
    (AppSettingsSection)config .GetSection(sectionName);
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.KeyValueInternalCollection' to type 'System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection'.