# How do I get a section from my winform app.config?

Tags: c#, winforms, casting, config, appsettings

I have reviewed the answers here, but my issue seems somewhat different than the Null return reported by others.

I am trying to grab a section from the app.config so I can do some processing on each name/value pair.  I seem unable to get the colection back from ConfigurationManager due to casting issues.

Using C# and .NET 4.5, I have been trying variations on this theme:

```
AppSettingsSection sec =
    (AppSettingsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings");
```

I first attempted to pull the values back into a generic, and used the expected casting error to define a type for the incoming collection.  However, each type I try to use gets the same error, can't cast type `abc` to `abc` (same type).

Obviously the problem is between the chair and keyboard, but Google isn't helping.  Any ideas?

Here is a snip of the app.config

```
<add key="TemplatePath" value="c:\temp\templates\"/>
<add key="deployDateToken" value="[deployDate]"/>
<add key="NavigateToFolderToken" value="[NavigateToFolder]"/>
<add key="contactToken" value="[ContactInfo]"/>
```

Comment: You are saying you can't cast from type `T` to type `T`, where both T's are the same type. Can you show a more elaborate example of what you are trying to do? Because generally, such a cast is either not needed, or the types are not castable.

Comment: The full error message itself can reveal much more information than what you typed. Thus, paste that here, or you get readers puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

You can say something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> EnumerateAppSettings()
{
  return ConfigurationManager
         .AppSettings
         .Cast<string>()
         .Select( key => new KeyValuePair<string,string>( key , ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] ) )
         ;
}

...

foreach ( KeyValuePair<string,string> item in EnumerateAppSettings() )
{
   // do something
}
```

Or even

```
Dictionary<string,string> appSettings = ConfigurationManager
                                        .AppSettings
                                        .Cast<string>()
                                        .ToDictionary( key => key , key => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] )
                                        ;
```

Or...simplest of all:

```
NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ;
```

If you want to get the actual `AppSettingsSection`, you'll need to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11117635/467473) to the question [How to get web.config appSettings as ConfigurationSection not NameValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117560/how-to-get-web-config-appsettings-as-configurationsection-not-namevaluecollectio).

Answer (score 0):

What about something like the following

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

foreach (var key in appSettings.AllKeys)
{
    appSettings[key]//do something
}
```